# Taking a picture and saving it into gallery in a separate folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made an application where the user can take a photo and save it into their gallery in a separate folder named "SOC". This works on one of my Android devices however on the other device the user can take the picture but the image doesn't save for some reason. The device the image saves on is Android 4.2 the device it does not save the image on is Android 5.0 not sure if this has anything to do with it. 
My Code is as fallows

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
public void onClickbtnCamera(View v)
{
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/SOC","QR_"+timeStamp+ ".png"));
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 1);

}
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {

        //Check for succesful result code
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            //Show your Toast when the result is a success.
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Picture is saved in your SOC gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 100, 0);
            toast.show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**. **Always** use a method to derive storage locations, such as `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. Also, bear in mind that few camera apps will save PNG files. And, bear in mind that some camera apps have bugs and therefore may fail to write to the location you request in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Have you any examples of how I would do this. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Camera/Content/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/camcon/CameraContentDemoActivity.java

Comment: I'm a newbie at Android development and I'm wondering what section of this Github code goes in my `onClick` event. Thanks

Comment: That's a complicated question, as it gets into a lot of other stuff about your activity, such as how you are handling configuration changes overall.